# Magento 2: To set 301 URL in Magento URL rewrites for this particular search

Tags: search, catalogsearch, 301-redirect

How to set 301 URL in Magento URL rewrites?

From

```
https://www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=%7Bquery%7D
```

To

```
https://www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=query
```

I have tried with below specified URLs in the **request path** and **target path** but not working.

```
/catalogsearch/result/?q=%7Bquery%7D 
catalogsearch/result/?q=%7Bquery%7D
```

**Target Path**

`catalogsearch/result/?q=query`

`/catalogsearch/result/?q=query`

May be this is duplicate of some 301 redirection related questions.